# How do I avoid running the setup method for a skipped Python unit test

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest

I have a set of test cases with a few skipped tests, but the setUp method is being run for the skipped tests. According to the documentation at https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html, Skipped tests will not have setUp() or tearDown() run around them, but its not true when I try it. What am I missing?

```
import unittest

def fun(x):
    return x + 1

class MyTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        print "** in Setup"

    def test_02(self):
        self.skipTest("** skipping, but dont want to run setUp")
        self.assertEqual(fun(4), 5)
```

output when I run the above Test

```
Testing started at 3:48 PM ...
** in Setup

** skipping, but dont want to run setUp
Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: How would unittest know not to run `setUp` before calling `test_02`? Mark tests you want to skip with a decorator.

Comment: @vaultah In Python 3.7, if you mark the tests you want to skip with a `@unittest.skip` decorator, then `setUp()` is still invoked.  I think it's a reasonable assumption that `unittest` should not set up unit tests when one explicitly declares that they should be skipped.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than calling `TestCase.skipTest`, you can decorate the method with [`unittest.skip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.skip):

```
import unittest

def fun(x):
    return x + 1

class MyTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        print "** in Setup"

    @unittest.skip('skip please...')
    def test_02(self):
        self.skipTest("** skipping, but dont want to run setUp")
        self.assertEqual(fun(4), 5)

unittest.main()
```

In this case, unittest marks the method so that it knows not to bother running `setUp` or `tearDown`.  With the version where you (directly or indirectly) raise `unittest.SkipTest` *inside* the test function, it's too late -- `setUp` has already been run by the time there is *any* indication that the test should be skipped.

Comment: I use `asynctest` library and `unittest.skip` decorator doesn't help me to not run `setUp` method for every skipped test.

Comment: What if the skip/ dont skip part was variable? how could I handle this>?